# PHP URL Adwords Variable

Tags: php, url, google-ads-api

From an Adwords URL I see this:

> http://someaddress.com?utm_expid=123456-8&**987654**&gclid=Cladskrjelasdjf

What I want to parse out of this with $_GET is the **987654** in the middle.  Is this possible since it's not a variable?

---

UPDATE:

Here's what I found to work:

```
$keys = array_keys($_GET);
foreach ($keys as $value) {
    if (preg_match('/9876/', $value)) {
        $acntKey = $value;
    }
}
echo "The account key value = " . $acntKey;

The account key value = 987654
```

The account key value can be any 9876** hence the preg_match. My only concern is if the 9876 shows up on another key - extremely unlikely.

Comment: I answered it with a way that it would always give you the account key without having to know the account number of even part of it. You will only be able to use your example with just 987654 or whatever the number is at the time, so it's not very dynamic. So any Adwords URL can be used with my example with out manually updating the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to loop it...

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
...
}
```

Will get you the key/pair value for everything in the $_GET var.

Which will give you:

```
utm_expid => 123456-8,
987654 => null,
gclid => Cladskrjelasdjf
```

Comment: Hummm, I want the 987654 to be a value and not the variable.  I'll have to play with this...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can use [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

```
$keys = array_keys($_GET);
```

Then You can loop through `$keys` to find the number you want.

Answer (score 0):

To give you more an exact answer which sounds like you might be looking for; this will give you that value.

```
 foreach($_GET as $keys=>$value){
    if($keys != "utm_expid" && $keys != "gclid"){
     echo $keys; // value is 987654
     $nVar = $keys; // you can then assign it to a new var too. 
    }
   }
```

The value will be stored in the new variable.

Comment: This will only work in one instance (987654). Since those are very dynamic URLs it'll likely only work once.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 I went based of off what he had **bolded** so I thought that is what he was referring to. I realize now it was only an example. Going based of **only** what he provided, the updated answer should get what he wants.